# Sed Insert symbol before in position

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have one problem with my sed command. Got string `foooooooBaaaar` and I need comma separate before `Baaaar` to be `fooooooo,Baaaar`. Maybe whom knows how can i do it and can explain me ? Thanks!

Comment: what is the rule of insertion? are those substrings static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a comma before an uppercase letter:

```
$ sed 's/[A-Z]/,&/' <<< "foooooooBaaaar"
fooooooo,Baaaar
```

**Explanation:**

- `s`: substitute
- `[A-Z]`: uppercase letter
- with comma followed by the matching letter(`&`)

To add a comma before `Baaaar` string:

```
$ sed 's/Baaaar/,&/' <<< "foooooooBaaaar"
```

Comment: It Works!  i change a little bit you code to:  sed -ri 's/ServicePassword/,&/' file.txt  because i have randomly changed string: 
701177775058ServicePassword:xxxxxxxxxxx , and need to separate comma before ServicePassword all the time, but all ok , i solve it with yours help! Thanks! :)